# Android: Why doesn't my second TextView show up, while the first one does?

Tags: java, android

i added a second `TextView` and it is supposed to be beneath the first `TextView` but now the first `TextView` is working but the second one isn't showing up.

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/state1"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/sayer1"
android:textSize="12sp" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" 
android:text="@string/state2"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:text="@string/sayer2"
android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which one is the problem? You have four and you say the second one is showing up. Second one down? `textView2`? Also, are the others showing correctly?

Comment: Also: why are you aligning the textView2 with its parent's bottom? Aren't you trying to put the thirdLine beneath it?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your top `RelativeLayout` has its height set to `?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight` and the first text views height is set to wrap content. Depending on the height of the first text view it could just be that the layout isn't high enough to show both

Change your top `RelativeLayout` to use a height of `wrap_content`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="6dip" >
```

Looking at these two text views:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" 
android:text="@string/state2"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:text="@string/sayer2"
android:textSize="16sp" />
```

This will not work as you are putting the second one at the bottom with `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and then you're trying to put something underneath it. But its aligned to the bottom so there is no space below it!

Changing those bottom two text views to following might do what you want:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:text="@string/sayer2"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
android:text="@string/state2"
android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i did but still there words are in the going upward the other not in other position

note: i use arabic language

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about the arabic language so can't help much there. But I have updated my answer to hopefully solve some other problems I spotted in your layout

Answer (score 1):

You need three things to make the others appear.

#### First:

Change this attribute `android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` to `android:width="match_parent"`

#### Second:

Set a width/height to your `TextView`s. **thirdLine** and **textView2** haven't a proper width/height. Try to make this:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

#### Finally:

Don't try to place a `TextView` below another which its alignment is `alignParentBottom`. Instead of this, try to add a container which its aligment is at the bottom of the global parent. See below:

**Try this formatting:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
// set a height to wrap_content/match_parent/fill_parent
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="state1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
        
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="sayer1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
    
    // if you want to align the latter text
    // to the bottom, make a container as...
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        
        // declare the width/height of the TextView
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:text="sayer2"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" 
            android:text="state2"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if it's the expected result. Hope this helps.

Comment: still didn't work this is my latest progress i hope you can help me more

Comment: Change all the width/height to `fill_parent` instead of `match_parent` as my update answer. It seems to work good for me.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: I've been advised that this answer is wrong, but it does highlight an issue in the layout simulator parser.  In that light, I'm going to leave this answer in-tact to document the flaw.

---

You accdententally added `@+id/TextView2` to the layout below.

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
```

Try this instead to reference the concrete id, and you'll need to add sizing parameters

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/textView2" 
  android:text="@string/state2"
  android:textSize="16sp" />
```

This works with only these changes in my android layout simulator, but you might need to move the definition `textView2` to be above where it's referenced.

Here's the file as it works in my layout builder:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="asdf"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="fdsa"
android:textSize="12sp" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
android:layout_below="@id/textView2" 
android:text="asdffdsa"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:text="string/sayer2"
android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its saying now  no resource found that matches the given name(@id/textView2"

Comment: yeah, that's because actually Paul's comment is wrong. Your first reference to the object was creating it, which in this case was correct (even though, for legibility, you should think about changing the order in which you declare your objects... YMMV)

Comment: @DigCamara I accept your criticism. :)  Though if this is really wrong, why is it being allowed without error in the layout builder?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer well, that's actually a defect in the parser. It should warn you at least, but sadly doesn't. For more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the layout you have works properly, you should be getting a "no resource found..." against **@id/textView2** since you are trying to reference it in

```
android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
```

within your "thirdLine" TextView **BEFORE** you have added the **textView2** into the relativelayout.

The order should be like this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_below="@id/textView1" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" " />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />
```

Do remember that when you have RelativeLayout the **order** in which you add your views doesn't matter, you can tell them where to position themselves.

What **must** always happen though is that you if you are **referencing** a view, it must be **above** the view that is referencing it. Wow that's confusing.

Let's say A wants to be below B. Then in your RelativeLayout, B must come BEFORE A.

Now that that's explained. In your **textView2** you have told it to align itself against its parent so that it goes to the **bottom** and **left**. Of course you can't have **thirdLine** below **textView2** since **textView2** is aligned in **bottom left**. Try instead:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_above="@+id/thirdLine" />
```

Also, isn't the IDE telling you to state "layout_width" and "layout_height"? For the TextViews. If this hasn't helped you at all, could you please draw a small picture of what you need so we may guide you better?

I'd also suggest stating the parent view's (Your RelativeLayout) height and width to "fill_parent" (API 7 and below) or "match_parent" (API 8 and above).

For the other views I'd go for

```
android:layout_width="match_parent" or "fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

But you can also have the width set to "wrap_content" whatever suits your UI better.